# Association of 4 tables in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 4 tables involved in this query.

`Campaign` - many to one business

`Business` - one to many client

`Client` - one to one contact

```
Contact
```

In contact there is the field `contact_name` which is unique. I need to retrieve all `campaigns` related to `contact`(via `client` and `business`) which `campaign` field `type` equals 2.

What is the best way to do it with hibernate?

In SQL is will look like this:

```
select * 
from campaign,contact, business, client 
where campaign.type=2 
and client.contact_id = contact.contact_id 
and contact.name = 'Josh' 
and client.business_id = business.business_id 
and campaign.campaign_id = business.business_id
```

Comment: Are the relations between the tables already configured with xml or annotations or is that part of the problem?

Comment: I am using annotation, and I did declare one to many many to one etc however, I need an efficient solution to retrieve the results

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following should work.

`from Compaign where Compaign.type=2 and compaign.business.client.contact.contact_name=:name`

Comment: is it the recommended way? not via any connections?

Comment: What do you mean with "connection"?

Comment: What do you think compaign.business.client.contact does? It does an inner join between compain and business, then an inner join between business and client, then en inner join between client and contact. Read the Hibernate documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Comment: it won't work. since business have many to one to many clients. I mean - each client has only one business but business could have many clients. I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can execute native SQL Queries too using **createSQLQuery()** method of Session.

You can also use Scalar Property to avoid the overhead of using ResultSetMetadata.
You can find more information on this from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)